# No output from python in terminal

Tags: python, shell, unix

Is it a way to hide every output from a Python script launched like that :

```
python myscript.py&
```

I tried to use

```
python myscript.py& > log.txt
```

But I get an output. I don't get it without the "&", that I need.

Comment: Define *doesn't work*; what happens when you use `> log.txt` and how does that differ from not using the redirect? Does the script write to `stderr` as well or instead?

Comment: Here is the script that I launched : https://github.com/tdicola/pi-catlaser/blob/master/server.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`> log.txt` only redirects output written to `stdout`. To completely capture all possible output, you also need to redirect `stderr`:

```
python myscript.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

Note that the ampersand to put the command in the background goes *at the end*, after the redirections. See [*All about redirection*](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) in the Bash Programming - Introduction HOWTO.

In your specific case, you are starting a Flask server; Flasks uses a the Python `logging` framework, and the default configuration is to create a logger based on the [`StreamHandler` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) which outputs to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

You can use the `logging` framework to configure logging differently; you could set a different handler to log to a specific file, for example, rather than use redirection. See the [logging HOWTO documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) for details, as well as the [Flask logging documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/).

Comment: Ok ! This line works : python myscript.py > log.txt 2>&1, but not if I run python myscript.py& > log.txt 2>&1

Comment: @cooow: no, because you'd put the `&` ampersand *at the end*, not before the redirects; use `python myscript.py > log.txt 2>&1 &`

Comment: @cooow: right, you didn't include that detail into your question at first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the `&` after `myscript.py` is telling your shell to open up a separate subprocess for that command, and doesn't pass the rest of the commandline in.

You need to pass the & at the end.

```
python myscript.py > log.txt &
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the problem : the "&" has to be in the end of the line.